# Laravel create command wont insert a value in database

Tags: laravel

Hello i am new to Laravel so currently im doing a CRUD. I have created this insert function that works well except one value is never inserted. This is the code below:

```
public function storeClient(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'nullable',
        'age'=>'required',
    ]);
    Client::create($request->all());
    dd($request->phone);
    return redirect('/')->with('msg', 'Client Saved successfully!.');
}
```

the `phone' => 'nullable'`, value will not insert in the database unless i update the existing values. I tried this command `dd($request->phone);` and it shows the correct value from the user input. Any idea why the value will be inserted as null on database?

[This is the value output when i make the `dd` command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNmP9.png)

I tried this other code which works well but im trying to use the default `create()` function of laravel. This is the other code i did that works well:

```
public function storeClient()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $client->name = request('name');
    $client->email = request('email');
    $client->phone_number = request('phone');
    $client->age = request('age');
    $client->save();
    return redirect('/')->with('msg','Client Saved successfully!');
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't add `phone` in the `Client`'s $fillable.

Comment: @RamyHerrira I have its like this `protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'email','phone_number','age',];`

Comment: @RamyHerrira its `phone_number` because thats the name in the database if i change it shows error saying no row was found with that name

Comment: @RamyHerrira i changed the name from `phone` to `phone_number` in the html form and works now.

Comment: @laraCoder Yes that makes sense, for this to work the fillable has to contain the exact names as the DB columns. But in order to 'map' the request variables to the correct column, the names in your html also have to match. It's explained in docs here [Mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first i did not like nullable here  'phone' => 'nullable',
then u should see what do you register in your Client table  phone_number  or phone,
$client->phone_number = request('phone');

i think you should rename your input name phone to phone_number and will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to use default create method the fields names must be same as in database.

```
$client->phone_number = request('phone');
```

this line works due to the name you entered manually.
to work with default create method change the name of field in database as phone.